# In an absence of gravity, does time flow faster or slower than on Earth?

Tags: general-relativity, time

I understand from my very limited knowledge of relativity that an object traveling at relativistic speeds essentially experiences the progression of time slow to a crawl. Since, according to [Einstein's GR theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity), gravity bends spacetime, does that mean that time is also slowed down by large amounts of gravity?

If I were in a place where there was absolutely no gravity in any way shape or form, would I experience time passing more quickly, and if so, by how much?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much faster would a Clock without gravity run?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68930/)

Answer (score 2):

> I understand from my very limited
>   knowledge of relativity that an object
>   traveling at relativistic speeds
>   essentially experiences the
>   progression of time slow to a crawl.

Well, proper time (the time measure by at clock that's moving at your same speed) is unaffected by you speed. Time dilation would be observed on clocks that are travelling faster than you.

> Since, according to Einstein's GR
>   theory , gravity bends spacetime,
>   does that mean that time is also
>   slowed down by large amounts of
>   gravity?

Yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation

> If I were in a place where there was absolutely no gravity in any way
>   shape or form, would I experience
>   time passing more quickly, and if so, by how much?

No, proper time doesn't vary. Nevertheless, you will see clocks where there's more gravity to run slower. How much depends on the metric.